# How do I fix my Django ImproperlyConfigured exception?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I've followed installations of Django using pip in a virtualenv since I'm learning Django. When the Django Book told me to type this in the Python shell,

```
from django import template
t = template.Template("My name is {{ name }}.")
```

I got this exception. I don't know how to solve this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "django/template/base.py", line 123, in __init__
    if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:
  File "django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATE_DEBUG,
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Can somebody walk me through? I'm using Mac OS X 10.8

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems that you are running python shell using the command `python`. So the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable is not available. Run your application specific python shell using

```
python manage.py shell
```

Read more about [manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-py-and-manage-py).

> manage.py sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.

Comment: Does it also mean that my system python shell doesn't have Django? Or, does the Django shell specifically run from `manage.py`?

Comment: Your system python shell will be having django specific settings. But if you want your project specific settings like `TEMPLATE_DEBUG`, `DEBUG`, etc., to work, you need open the shell using `python manage.py shell`.

Comment: I get that error (ImproperlyConfigured) when running `python manage.py shell`... any thoughts?... this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 4):

you need to run the django shell so it loads the settings

```
python manage.py shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Django needs your application specific settings.
Since it is already inside your manage.py just run  :

python manage.py shell

This should resolve the issue fast-enough