# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. Even though I have tried all methods of configuration I receive the same error

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-scraping, web-development-server

I am getting the error even though I have configured DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULES accordingly.

Error:django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
Here is my views.py:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
from models import *
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
def index(request):
    session=request.Session() 
    session.headers={"User-Agent":"Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
    url="https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/today/l/9d531fc505eb4a93a90a7e8303ccaa22a142c9370b68391129de5019ee7adf5b"
    content=session.get(url,verify=False).content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'today_nowcard-temp'}):
        head=hit.text
        summ=(hit.next_sibling.text)
        weather=News()
        weather.header=head
        weather.summary=summ
        print(head)
        print(summ)
        weather.save()
    return redirect("../")
def news_list(request):
    weathers=News.objects.all()
    context={
        'object_list': weathers,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

This is settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'th9v0%i9^#4a30t3bn*0w_1qm9ci&(8q%xd*q+&*h1amyr77j9'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'news.apps.NewsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'Learn.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Learn.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'News',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'gateexam',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets') 
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

This is models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class News(models.Model):
    header=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary=models.CharField(max_length=100)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.header
```

Below is my workspace:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL7PT.jpg]

The other app calc runs without any error.

Comment: how do you run your app/server?

Comment: python manage.py runserver

Comment: where do you have file `settings.py` ? if you have `Learn/settings.py` then you can try `python manage.py runserver --settings Learn.settings`. Did you change folder names ? Strange is that `calc` works but you don't have `INSTALLED_APPS = ["calc"]`. What is `'news.apps.NewsConfig'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ? Is this folder with application ? If you have application in folder `news` then you need `INSTALLED_APPS= ["news"]`, not `INSTALLED_APPS=['news.apps.NewsConfig']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the virtual environment; it was by default using another virtual environment and not the virtual environment of the project.
The name of the virtual environment was res I activated it by going to the virtual environment directory and running the command:

```
Scripts\activate
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? Which 'virtual environment directory' did you go to? your project directory or the .virtualenvironment directory? I'm struggling with this too and going absolutely mad. can't get my project started.

Comment: I went in the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

***Run*** `Python Manage.py shell` and also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129515/how-do-i-fix-my-django-improperlyconfigured-exception) solution